# Python Equivalent to Ruby's Throw/Catch

Tags: python, ruby, dependency-injection

I am following along with [Building Git](https://shop.jcoglan.com/building-git/) but implementing it in Python instead of Ruby. I have run into a place where the Ruby implementation is depending on a feature of Ruby that doesn't seem to have a Pythonic equivalent.

My understanding is that Ruby's [Throw/Catch](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/catch-and-throw-exception-in-ruby/) mechanism can be used as a form of flow control, allowing you to return from a method without actually returning. A method throws a value. Then, each method in the stack passes along that value until a method can catch it.

It is an alternative to:

- Returning a value from a method
- Using Raise/Rescue and Exceptions

I am writing classes that encapsulate subcommands of a program. I would like to be able to run the command then exit with a status set using a method inherited from a superclass.

```py
class Base:
    """
    This class is the base class that all subcommands inherit from.
    """

    def exit(self, status = 0):
        """
        Exit the calling method using the specified status.
        """
        self.status = status
        # TODO, throw status?


class Add(Base):
    """
    This class implements the add command.
    """

    def run(self):
        """
        Run the add subcommand.
        """"

        # Example of where we should exit before the end of the method
        # An exception is called by a dependency of the subcommand.
        try:
            raise Exception()
        except:
            self.exit(128) # This should cause the run() method to return
    
        print("This line should not be reached")
```

The reason that I am using this design is so that I can use dependency injection and more easily test the commands with an automated test framework such as Pytest. Rather than using `sys.exit()` directly, I can wait until the subcommand returns and then get its status:

```py
def test_add():
    """
    This tests a certain execution path of the add subcommand.
    """
    cmd = Add()
    cmd.run()
    assert cmd.status == 128
```

What is the Pythonic equivalent of using the inherited callee `exit()` method to force the caller method `run()` to return? I am guessing that I am going to have to simply return an integer value from each `run()` method and get rid of `exit()`, but I wanted to ask and see if anyone else has any other ideas.

Comment: why not `return self.exit(128)` ?

Comment: @TomHuibregtse: I am not aware that Python has something like throw/catch, but perhaps using [continuations](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html) could act as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

As Albin Paul commented above, I should use `return self.exit(128)`.